# Asymmetric graphs stable under 3-dimensional Weisfeiler-Leman

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

The $k$-dimensional Weisfeiler-Leman algorithm ($k$-WL) is a method for partitioning the $k$-tuples of vertices of a graph $G$ in an approximation of the orbits of the automorphism group $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ on $V(G)^k$. One begins by labeling the $k$-tuples according to their isomorphism type, i.e., $(u_1, \ldots, u_k)$ and $(v_1, \ldots, v_k)$ receive the same label if the map $u_i \mapsto v_i$ (exists and) is an isomorphism of the subgraphs of $G$ induced by $\{u_1, \ldots, u_k\}$ and $\{v_1, \ldots, v_k\}$. Let $L_0(u_1, \ldots, u_k)$ be the label assigned to $(u_1, \ldots, u_k)$ by this initial step. At each step the new label $L_{i+1}(u_1, \ldots, u_k)$ is defined as the ordered pair
$$(L_i(u_1, \ldots, u_k),\{(L_i(v,u_2, \ldots, u_k), L_i(u_1,v,\ldots,u_k), \ldots, L_i(u_1, \ldots, u_{k-1},v)):v \in V(G)\}),$$
where the second coordinate is a multiset rather than a set.

The process stops when the partition of $V(G)^k$ according to the labels stabilizes.

Note that 1-dimensional Weisfeiler-Leman is a bit of an exception: here one begins by labeling each vertex with its degree and then at each step the labeling is refined by adding to the label of a vertex the multiset of labels of its neighbors.

For any $k \ge 1$, the resulting partition of $V(G)^k$ is necessarily a coarse-graining of the orbit partition of the action of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ on $V(G)^k$. The two partitions need not coincide. In the extreme case, one can have that the graph $G$ is stable under $k$-WL (i.e. the partitioning stops after the initial labeling by isomorphism types), but $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is trivial (in which case we say $G$ is *asymmetric*) and thus the partition into orbits is the discrete partition.

As an example, any regular graph is stable under 1-WL, but there are regular graphs on 10 vertices having no automorphisms. Similarly, strongly regular graphs are precisely the graphs that are stable under 2-WL, but there are asymmetric strongly regular graphs on 25 vertices.

**Question:** Are there any graphs known that are stable under 3-WL that are also asymmetric? Preferably I'd like the graphs to be as small as possible.

Alternatively, I would ask for something perhaps slightly easier. Given the partition of $V(G)^k$ resulting from the $k$-WL algorithm, let us refer to the parts containing tuples of the form $(v,v, \ldots, v)$ as the *fibres* of the partition. Then I ask the following:

**Question:** Are there graphs $G$ for which it is known that the partition of $V(G)^3$ resulting from 3-WL has only one fibre, and $G$ is asymmetric?

For the analogous question for 2-WL, an asymmetric distance regular graph would give an example. Such a graph is not stable under 2-WL (if the diameter is greater than 2), but 2-WL results in a single fibre (the resulting partition of $V(G)^2$ is the partition according to the distance between the two vertices in a given ordered pair).

Comment: Collinearity graphs of generalised quadrangles (GQs) are 3-WL stable. I won't be surprised if there are known asymmetric GQs.

Comment: By the way, pseudo-Paley tournaments also satisfy 3-WL. I proved this long time ago, in https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00053382
(again, I don't know whether there are such asymmetric things, but I'm certain there must be some...)